# choosing alternate tag in incoming xml using xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt

Below is my incoming xml:
I want the comments to go in the third column of the table and not able to do so as it has the same 'arg' element as others however name parameter is unique.
Can anyone please help?

Below is my incoming XML

```
<request>
    <url>/serviceGenerator/Common</url>
    <base-url>/serviceGenerator/Common</base-url>
    <args src="url" />
    <args src="body">
        <arg name="YDQ1">DQ1YES</arg>
        <arg name="DQ1">sdasdsadsdsd</arg>
        <arg name="DQ2" />
        <arg name="DQ3" />
        <arg name="RQ1" />
        <arg name="RQ2" />
        <arg name="RQ3" />
    </args>
</request>
```

Below is my XSLt code

```
<table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <i>Questions</i>
        </th>
        <th>
            <i>Answers</i>
        </th>
        <th>
            <i>Comments</i>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="request/args[@src = 'body']/arg">
            <xsl:variable name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 1, 3)"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="idvalue">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(., 4, 3)"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:message>output id  <xsl:value-of select="$id"/></xsl:message>
            <xsl:message>output id  value<xsl:value-of select="$idvalue"/></xsl:message>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$questions/Questions/Question[@id = $id]/Desc/text()"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="$idvalue" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="'I want comments to be sdasdsadsdsd'" />
            </td>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not code snippets.

Comment: I suppose by comments you mean text. In that case you want to change your last <td> to <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>

Comment: Yes Christian, I want the value of this tag <arg name="DQ1">sdasdsadsdsd</arg> into td for comments

Comment: @michael.hor257k sure, I will make sure of it going forward

Comment: Voted to close.